# JavaFX DragView Image has lowered opacity compared to actual image... Can that be changed?

Tags: windows, image, javafx, drag-and-drop, opacity

I have been working on using Drag and Drop with JavaFX, and one thing I notice is that items are given lowered opacity compared to their actual images, as well as the larger the image the made "Faded/transparent" the image gets. I am working on am application that can drag fairly large items which end up almost invisible when dragging, which defeats the purpose of using a DragView Image in the first place, and makes this unusable for larger items (the way I'm using the DragView I want the images to be a certain size compared to the scene in which I'm dragging onto).

My application essentially has 2 Windows (Stages) where the data is in one Stage and I get the item from a list and drag it onto the scene.  The DragView image is a representation of the object going onto the scene, so when I drop the DragView Image, it gets dropped exactly into place on the scene, so the DragView is important to my overall application.

Just a NOTE: There is also backing data in my transfer in order to recreate the box, as well as additional data that gets transferred with the Drag and Drop.

I tried looking at the FX DragView Internal code but didn't find anything that sets the Opacity or anything like that, so one of my assumptions of "it's built into the OS" is something I keep thinking about, as lowered opacity is something I remember being built in, and when trying it it does happen, but very very slight, and not as bad as what I'm experiencing (Also possible that since the icons are much smaller they don't run into the "larger image opacity issue."

I am running Windows 7 64-Bit for those who are wondering.

My question is, is it possible to change the opacity settings of the Drag and Drop ImageView either via JavaFX or possibly Native with using something along the lines of JNI?

I don't have any example code at the moment, but can add if someone is interested, but I'm sure for those who know about Drag and Drop ImageViews should already know about the opacity.

Thank you all.

Comment: Drag-and-Drop is typically meant for transferring _data_, where the image is simply representational of that data; large images are semi-transparent because it's useful to see under them and thus where you're going to drop the data. I'm not personally aware of a way to change this through JavaFX, but perhaps if you [edit] your question to add a [mcve] demonstrating what you're trying to do maybe someone can suggest a different approach to Drag-and-Drop (assuming you don't need to transfer data _between_ applications).

Comment: @Slaw Thanks you.  There is additional data in the DnD as well. I have a window(stage) with data where users drag an image into the main window(stage) and then will drop the image onto certain parts of the scene which then turns that image into the real object which is a 3D Box.  The DragView is is important in that aspect.  Since I use a second window it seems DnD is something that I need.  You mention that you don't know how to change the opacity in Java, but do you have knowledge of it in another language, or at the OS Level that I might be able to look into?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of a native way to change the opacity (lack of knowledge rather than knowing if it is or isn't possible). Note that such a fix would likely be platform-specific and possibly difficult to use in conjunction with JavaFX's normal DnD handling. I was going to suggest using a _full press-drag-release_ gesture in combination with a `Popup` holding your image, but apparently said gesture doesn't work between `Window`s (the nodes in the other window don't receive any `MouseDragEvent`s). Though maybe you could still utilize the `Popup` idea somehow.